# Textbox into drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net

In my code I have drop down and textbox Now the issue is I want to hide the textbox and use the same functionality to drop-down instead of changing the backend there is any other ways of doing (in asp.net).

In my code I have drop down and textbox Now the issue is I want to hide the textbox and use the same functionality to drop-down instead of changing the backend there is any other ways of doing (in asp.net).but same functionality of textbox

Answer (score 0):

To hide a textbox and use the same functionality as a dropdown instead of changing the backend, you can use JavaScript or jQuery. Here's an example of how to do this using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDropdown').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dropdown Option 1') {
      $('#myTextbox').hide();
    } else {
      $('#myTextbox').show();
    }
  });
});
</script>

<select id="myDropdown">
  <option value="Dropdown Option 1">Dropdown Option 1</option>
  <option value="Dropdown Option 2">Dropdown Option 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="myTextbox" style="display: none;">
```

In this example, by changing the `myDropdown` field, `myTextbox` field will be hidden or displayed.